# Removing repeated string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have problem one of my string has repeated url inside and I want to remove it. What's the best way to do it in javascript?

Following is example of string I referring to.

var str = "http://www.example.comhttp://www.example.com"

Comment: Is it always the exact same strong twice?

Comment: How about fix the code which creates that string?

Comment: @Teemu it's not the code is error in xml feed of blog which they need to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to reassign `str` to half of itself.

```
str = str.substring(str.length/2)
```

(This assumes the string will always follow the same format as the example you gave.)